# LTE broadcasr or eMBMS is a RESTFull service ?

Tags: lte

LTE Broadcast (eMBMS) enables a Single Frequency
Network (SFN) broadcast capability within LTE, so that the same content
can be sent to a large number of users at the same time, resulting in a
more efficient use of network resources than each user requesting the
same content and then having the content unicast to each user. eMBMS uses HTTP protocol , so wanted to know if it is a REStfull api?

Comment: [An architecture style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is not the same as a low-level protocol.  I'm not sure what it is you're asking here.

Comment: @okoto- eMBMS implements broadcasting feature using HTTP protocol(implementation), so wanted to know if it falls in the the category of Restfull api?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no - eMBMS is more than just an interface, as Makoto says, it is a set of specifications that make up a Mobile Multicast solution.

There is a good overview which should illustrate this here:

- http://www.slideshare.net/zahidtg/lte-embms-technology-overview